# Disable Haskell type coercion

Tags: haskell, coercion

I have example based on [hyperloglog](https://github.com/ekmett/hyperloglog). I'm trying to parametrize my `Container` with size, and use [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.2/docs/Data-Reflection.html) to use this parameter in functions on containers.

```
import           Data.Proxy
import           Data.Reflection

newtype Container p = Container { runContainer :: [Int] }
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Reifies p Integer => Monoid (Container p) where
  mempty = Container $ replicate (fromIntegral (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy p))) 0
  mappend (Container l) (Container r) = undefined
```

My lame Monoid instance defines `mempty` based on reified parameter, and doing some "type-safe" `mappend`. It works perfectly when I'm trying to sum containers of different size, failing with type error.

However it's still can be tricked with `coerce`, and I'm looking for way to block it at compile time:

```
ghci> :set -XDataKinds
ghci> :m +Data.Coerce
ghci> let c3 = mempty :: Container 3
ghci> c3
ghci> Container {runContaner: [0,0,0]}
ghci> let c4 = coerce c3 :: Container 4
ghci> :t c4
ghci> c4 :: Container 4
ghci> c4
ghci> Container {runContainer: [0,0,0]}
```

Adding type role doesn't help

```
type role Container nominal
```

Comment: GHC 7.10 throws a lot of errors due to missing `LANGUAGE` annotations in your original code. Could you add them?

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you do it in a `.hs` file? GHCi can be weird about module boundaries. I'm quite sure `hyperloglog` has a role declaration of its own.

Comment: Weird... the role annotation should indeed prevent these coercions.

Comment: Not relevant here and you probably know already, but I'd remark that this is not a valid monoid instance because `(mempty<>mempty) :: Container 1` gives `Container [0,0] ≠ mempty`. You could make it valid with e.g. `mappend ∝ zipWith (+)`.

Comment: @Zeta https://gist.github.com/ezhulenev/f7913740e8971f9a60ce4c5677a0f3f3 - it's a lot there, not all of them relevant to this particular question though

Comment: @leftaroundabout oh yeah, I should better put undefined there

Comment: @dfeuer yeah, I can do the same trick in .hs file and compile it

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that your example is *based on* `hyperloglog` rather than *using* it. Ha. Side note to Antal's answer: you can conditionally expose a `Coercible` instance, packaged as a `Coercion`, from a module that defines an abstract type. `hyperloglog`, for example, offers a function that checks whether two distribution types reflect the same configuration and, if so, gives you a `Coercion` between them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `newtype`s are coercible to their representation as long as the constructor is in scope – indeed, this is a big part of the motivation for `Coercible`.  And `Coercible` constraints are like any other type class constraint, and are automatically searched and put together for you, only even more so.  Thus, `coerce c3` is finding that you have

```
instance Coercible (Container p) [Int]
instance Coercible [Int] (Container p')
```

for all `p` and `p'`, and happily building the composite coercion for you via

```
instance (Coercible a b, Coercible b c) => Coercible a c
```

If you don't export the `Container` constructor – as you probably want to do anyway! – then it's no longer known that the `newtype` is equal to its representation (you lose the first two instances above), and you get the desired error in other modules:

```
ContainerClient.hs:13:6:
    Couldn't match type ‘4’ with ‘3’
    arising from trying to show that the representations of
      ‘Container 3’ and
      ‘Container 4’ are the same
    Relevant role signatures: type role Container nominal nominal
    In the expression: coerce c3
    In an equation for ‘c4’: c4 = coerce c3
```

However, you'll always be able to break your invariants in the module where you define the `newtype` (via `coerce` or otherwise).

---

As a side note, you probably *don't* want to use a record-style accessor here and export it; that lets users use record-update syntax to change out code from under you, so

```
c3 :: Container 3
c3 = mempty

c3' :: Container 3
c3' = c3{runContainer = []}
```

becomes valid.  Make `runContainer` a free-standing function instead.

---

We can verify that we're getting the composition of the two `newtype`-representation constraints by looking at the Core (via `-ddump-simpl`): within the module that defines `Container` (which I've also called `Container`), the output is (if we remove the export list)

```
c4 :: Container 4
[GblId, Str=DmdType]
c4 =
  c3
  `cast` (Container.NTCo:Container[0] <GHC.TypeLits.Nat>_N <3>_N
          ; Sym (Container.NTCo:Container[0] <GHC.TypeLits.Nat>_N <4>_N)
          :: Container 3 ~R# Container 4)
```

It's a bit hard to read, but the important thing to see is `Container.NTCo:Container[0]`: the `NTCo` is a `newtype` coercion between the `newtype` `Container p` and its representation type.  `Sym` turns this around, and `;` composes two constraints.

Call the final constraint `γₓ`; then the whole typing derivation is

```
Sym :: (a ~ b) -> (b ~ a)
-- Sym is built-in

(;) :: (a ~ b) -> (b ~ c) -> (a ~ c)
-- (;) is built-in

γₙ :: k -> (p :: k) -> Container p ~ [Int]
γₙ k p = Container.NTCo:Container[0] <k>_N <p>_N

γ₃ :: Container 3 ~ [Int]
γ₃ = γₙ GHC.TypeLits.Nat 3

γ₄ :: Container 4 ~ [Int]
γ₄ = γₙ GHC.TypeLits.Nat 4

γ₄′ :: [Int] ~ Container 4
γ₄′ = Sym γ₄

γₓ :: Container 3 ~ Container 4
γₓ = γ₃ ; γ₄′
```

---

Here are the source files I used:

Container.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables,
             RoleAnnotations, PolyKinds, DataKinds #-}

module Container (Container(), runContainer) where

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Reflection
import Data.Coerce

newtype Container p = Container { runContainer :: [Int] }
    deriving (Eq, Show)
type role Container nominal

instance Reifies p Integer => Monoid (Container p) where
  mempty = Container $ replicate (fromIntegral (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy p))) 0
  mappend (Container l) (Container r) = Container $ l ++ r

c3 :: Container 3
c3 = mempty

-- Works
c4 :: Container 4
c4 = coerce c3
```

ContainerClient.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

module ContainerClient where

import Container
import Data.Coerce

c3 :: Container 3
c3 = mempty

-- Doesn't work :-)
c4 :: Container 4
c4 = coerce c3
```